# AdMob interstitial ad is not loading

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to implement an interstitial ad on in my way to the activity `Two`. But I my ad is not loading for some reason. I am new to java and tried to follow the AdMob instruction but I'm still not sure what I am missing and why the ad unit is not being loaded.

This is my activity `One`:

```
Button goFree;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/xxxxxxxx");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            startActivity(new Intent(One.this, Two.class));
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
        }
    });

    Button goFree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goFree);
    goFree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startTwo();
        }
    });
}

public void startTwo() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        startActivity(new Intent(One.this, Two.class));
    }
}
```

It logs the `The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.` when I click the Button to go to the second activity. What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add ,

```
MobileAds.initialize(LoginActivity.this,
                "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
```

See This :-

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);

    MobileAds.initialize(LoginActivity.this,
                        "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
          //rest of code here
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

Declare global variable :

```
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
```

Below code use in oncreate or as per need :

```
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

    // set the ad unit ID
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("5ADF8BFD1F030BF7ED41A52D88C63B9C").build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            showInterstitial();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {

        }
    });
```

Show by below method.

```
private void showInterstitial() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```

Use this id for a while :

```
<string name="interstitial_full_screen">ca-app-pub-2330175674430713/9772460509</string>
```

Sometime your admob code is not working. Try with this Sure it will work.

Thankyou hope this will help you.